# Cuando imprimo con printf me da error pero con system.out.println si me va porque?

Tags: java

He hecho un código para practicar los arrays (recién estoy empezando) pero cuando intento imprimir con formato (printf) no me va. ¿Alguna solución? No se si tiene que ver con si el uso del printf no es así. Pd: Soy nuevo lo siento por lo cutre del programa.

código que me va mal (con printf)

```
public class PracticaMatriz {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double acumulado;

    double interes= 0.10;

    double [] [] saldo  = new double [6] [5];

    for (int i = 0; i < saldo.length; i++) {

        saldo [i] [0] = 10000;

        acumulado = 10000;

        for (int j = 1; j < saldo.length-1 ; j++) {

            acumulado = acumulado + (acumulado * interes);

            saldo [i] [j] = acumulado;
        }

        interes = interes+ 0.01;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < saldo.length; i++) {

     if (i != 0 ) {

         System.out.println();
    }   

        for (int j = 0; j < saldo.length - 1; j++) {

            System.out.printf("%1.2" ,saldo [i] [j]);

              System.out.print(" ");

        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Si intentas con **%1.2f**

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si añades "f", ya que "f" formatea los números de coma flotante:

```
System.out.printf("%1.2f" ,saldo [i] [j]);
```

Esta respuesta te puede servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437315/java-util-unknownformatconversionexception.

Aquí puedes encontrar la explicación del printF: https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias no me di cuenta del fallo.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado marca mi respuesta como solucionada y me ayudas a mi y a alguien más que tenga la misma duda. Gracias.

Comment: Lo hice bien ? ¿Te sale respuesta solucionada?

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias.